# MVC4 RouteConfig params return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My `Booking Controller` have the following code

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

and my `routeConfig` have the below route mappings

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Search",
            url: "{controller}/{location}/{checkIn}/{checkOut}/{no}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", location = UrlParameter.Optional, checkIn = UrlParameter.Optional, checkOut = UrlParameter.Optional, no = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "booking",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Booking", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name=UrlParameter.Optional }
        );}
```

but when I access the page `http://localhost:59041/booking/index/1/libin` both params returns `null`.

Comment: does your request.querystring have any value?

Comment: Your example is showing your ID as an integer (1) but your route is a string.  Part of the issue is 2 optional string parameters.  CAn you change the Id to an integer?

Comment: aaaaah, @MarkOreta, thats why shaharoozi's answer is correct. That's what i missed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> see [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Routing.html) book
>
> As your application becomes more complex you are likely going to
>   register multiple routes. When you do this its important that you
>   consider the order that that you register them. When the routing
>   engine attempts to locate a matching route, it simply enumerates the
>   collection of routes and it stops enumerating as soon as it find a
>   match.
>
> Add a comment This can cause plenty of problems if you’re not
>   expecting it. Let’s look at an examples where this can be a problem:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    >     "generic", // Route name
    >     "{site}", // URL with parameters
    >     new { controller = "SiteBuilder", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults );
    > 
    > routes.MapRoute(
    >     "admin", // Route name
    >     "Admin", // URL with parameters
    >     new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults );
```

The snippet above registers two routes. The first route

> contains a single placeholder segment and sets the default value of
>   the controller parameter to SiteBuilder. The second route contains a
>   single constant segment and sets the default value of the controller
>   parameter to Admin.
>
> Both of these routes are completely valid, but the order in which they
>   are mapped may cause unexpected problems because the first route
>   matches just about any value entered, which means that it will be the
>   first to match
>
> http://example.com/Admin and since the routing engine stops after
>   finding the first match, the second route would never get used.
>
> So, be sure to keep this scenario in mind and consider the order in
>   which you define custom routes.

You should write booking routes at first

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "booking",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Booking", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name=UrlParameter.Optional }
        );}
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Search",
            url: "{controller}/{location}/{checkIn}/{checkOut}/{no}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", location = UrlParameter.Optional, checkIn = UrlParameter.Optional, checkOut = UrlParameter.Optional, no = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: You're right that this route should be 1st. But why would the Default route fail. I didn't even notice the right route b/c I assumed the url was meant for the Default one.

Comment: now I see, the int will fail to match and default route will fail.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,name= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: Thanks... that was the issue.. I am very new to MVC. Have a great day.. :)